# Parabrahman as generator of thoughts

Tags: scripture, brahma, human

Every human (in fact living organism) has thoughts throughout the lifetime.

Thoughts occur to humans during jagrit and Swapna avasthas.

Modern science believes that the brain is responsible for the generation of thoughts in a human being.

In Hinduism, it is generally believed that para brahman generates thoughts for an individual and the human may feel that the thoughts are generated by own self.

Do any scripture explicitly tells that the para brahman is the only entity responsible for the generation of thoughts based on the samskaras/karmic impressions of the jiva?

Note that para Brahman in this question refers to either saguna Brahman or nirguna Brahman...

Comment: There is one view of yoga (I forgot where exactly it is), there the concept is like this: 'Infinite Thoughts are already present in the universe and a being attracts those thoughts to himself based on the Satva-Raja-Tamas distribution of his body and several other factors, body and various factors attached basically just act like a magnet which pulls those thoughts and they reach mind and manifest there...

Comment: Mind is a bundle of Vasanas (subtle desires). Through Vasanas bondage is caused. Avidya of the jiva causes bondage. I do not think there is a concept in Advaita where Nirguna brahman will generate thoughts. See Moksha gita for more discussion of this. https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/moksha/moksh_06.html

Comment: @Tezz I’ve heard same type of thing, except the more I have try to understand, the more I’m leaning towards the idea of no free will down to thoughts, emotions, of course words, actions. No free will down to the most tiny little details.

Comment: Yeah I think the thoughts don’t come from us, neither does anything else. Which is weird when you first realize, but makes sense w/ the time cycles & karma.